# Use JQuery to iterate over deep XML structure - IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

In JS I have a variable `data` with following XML:

```
<data>
    <delivery>
        <checklist>Pre-Vehicle Check Bulk</checklist>
        <delivery>800056799</delivery>
        <shipment>105065995</shipment>
        <driverName>John Doe</driverName>
        <driverLanguage>NL</driverLanguage>
        <country>Belgium</country>
        <product>01248741</product>
        <productDescription>Metam 200%-33</productDescription>
        <location>P0204A</location>
    </delivery>
    <questions>
        <question>
            <id>Question-1</id>
            <driver>true</driver>
            <operator>true</operator>
            <isAnswered>false</isAnswered>
            <answer/>
            <options>
                <option>OK</option>
                <option>NOK</option>
                <option>NA</option>
            </options>
        </question>
        <question>
            <id>Question-2</id>
            <driver>true</driver>
            <operator>false</operator>
            <isAnswered>false</isAnswered>
            <answer/>
            <options>
                <option>OK</option>
                <option>NOK</option>
            </options>
        </question>
    </questions>
</data>
```

I'm creating a JS object based on this XML. The result should be an array with questions. Each question has its attributes and an array of options. So basically the same structure as you see in the XML under the `questions` tag

Here is the JS code to generate the object:

```
var questions = [];
$(data).find("question").each(function(){
    var options = [];
    $(this).find("option").each(function(){
        options.push($(this).text());
    });

    questions.push({
        id : $(this).find("id").text(),
        driver : $(this).find("driver").text(),
        operator : $(this).find("operator").text(),
        isAnswered : $(this).find("isAnswered").text(),
        answer : $(this).find("answer").text(),
        title : $(this).find("title").text(),
        text : $(this).find("text").text(),
        text_driver : $(this).find("text_driver").text(),
        options : options
    });
});
```

Now the problem is that the options don't get added. From the debugger I can see that after the first `.each` the `<option>` tags are removed from the current node `this`. So the value is:

```
<options>OKNOKNA</options>
```

How can I achieve looping over multiple XML levels with JQuery?

**EDIT**: it seems to be related to IE9, I need to get it working on this specific browser.

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/4shLrL2q/ The result has an array of options.

Comment: @squint Indeed it works in chrome, I should have added my development needs to run on my worst enemy: IE9

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it thinks those are HTML `option` elements in an invalid location. Try using [`jQuery.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse it before passing it to `$`. http://jsfiddle.net/4shLrL2q/1/

Comment: @squint Indeed!! Thank you so much :) please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing IE9 thinks those are HTML option elements in an invalid location.

Use `jQuery.parseXML()` to parse it before passing it to `$`.